# How to extract subgraph in igraph

Tags: r, igraph

I want to extract a subgraph around that node.

```
library(visNetwork)
library(igraph)
library(dplyr)

g<-data.frame(a=c(LETTERS[1:5], LETTERS[2:6]),b=c(LETTERS[2:6],  LETTERS[7:11])) %>% 
        as.matrix %>% graph.edgelist() 

visIgraph(g) %>% 
       visHierarchicalLayout(sortMethod = "directed", 
                             direction = "LR",levelSeparation = 300)
```

I would like to extract subgraph start from "D",  like this

```
data.frame(a=c(LETTERS[1:5], LETTERS[2:6]), b=c(LETTERS[2:6], LETTERS[7:11])) %>% 
    as.matrix %>% .[c(4,5,8,9,10),1:2] %>% 
    graph.edgelist() %>% visIgraph() %>% 
    visHierarchicalLayout(sortMethod = "directed", 
                          direction = "LR", levelSeparation = 300)
```

Is there a way to get it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried the induced.subgraph() function?

```
new.vertices<- V(g)[-c(1,2,3,7,8)]
g.sub <- induced.subgraph(graph = g, new.vertices)
visIgraph(g.sub) %>% 
  visHierarchicalLayout(sortMethod = "directed", 
                        direction = "LR",levelSeparation = 300)
```

Comment: Thank you very much Jonathan, is any way to find subgraph path for "D" instead of 1,2,3,7,8?

Comment: You could do it the other way around by writing inline `new.vertices<- V(g)[c(4,5,6,9,10,11)]`, but other than that I would not know of a function because you do have to specify all edges or vertices to be included. You could try writing a function that goes through the alphabet and selects every edge where the vertices > c sort of. Eventually you still have to subtract a list of vertices